# Scala: How to combine parser combinators from different objects

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

Given a family of objects that implement parser combinators, how do I combine the parsers? Since [`Parsers.Parser`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers.Parser.html) is an inner class, and in Scala [inner classes are bound to the *outer object*](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/115), the story becomes slightly complicated.

Here's an example that attempts to combine two parsers from different objects.

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

class BinaryParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def anyrep: Parser[Any] = rep(any)
  def any: Parser[Any] = zero | one
  def zero: Parser[Any] = "0"
  def one: Parser[Any] = "1"
}

object LongChainParser extends BinaryParser {
  def parser1: Parser[Any] = zero~zero~one~one
}

object ShortChainParser extends BinaryParser {
  def parser2: Parser[Any] = zero~zero
}

object ExampleParser extends BinaryParser {
  def parser: Parser[Any] = (LongChainParser.parser1
    ||| ShortChainParser.parser2) ~ anyrep

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(parseAll(parser, args(0) ))
  }
}
```

This results to the following error:

```
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : ShortChainParser.Parser[Any]
 required: LongChainParser.Parser[?]
         def parser: Parser[Any] = (LongChainParser.parser1 
           ||| ShortChainParser.parser2) ~ anyrep
```

I've found the solution to this problem already, but since it was brought up 
recently on scala-user ML ([Problem injecting one parser into another](http://old.nabble.com/Problem-injecting-one-parser-into-another-tt28219190.html)), it's probably worth putting it here too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The quick answer is to use the `trait`s instead of hosting the parsers in `object`s:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

trait BinaryParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def anyrep: Parser[Any] = rep(any)
  def any: Parser[Any] = zero | one
  def zero: Parser[Any] = "0"
  def one: Parser[Any] = "1"
}

trait LongChainParser extends BinaryParser {
  def parser1: Parser[Any] = zero~zero~one~one
}

trait ShortChainParser extends BinaryParser {
  def parser2: Parser[Any] = zero~zero
}

object ExampleParser extends LongChainParser with ShortChainParser  {
  def parser: Parser[Any] = (parser1 ||| parser2) ~ anyrep

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(parseAll(parser, args(0) ))
  }
}
```

Because the combinator operators like `~` and `|` are written against the inner class, escalating the parser references to class-level by saying `BinaryParser#Parser[_]` doesn't do you any good. Using traits solves all that inner-class issues since both `Parser[Any]` from `LongChainParser` and `ShortChainParser` now refer to the inner class of `ExampleParser` object.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question and of course for answering it! This is exactly what I was looking for.