# How to combine parsers with different types of Elem

Tags: scala, types, parser-combinators

I'm trying to create a parser that combines Regex parsers and a custom parser I have. I've looked at [Scala: How to combine parser combinators from different objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650254/scala-how-to-combine-parser-combinators-from-different-objects), but that question and answers deal with parsers that have the same type of `Elem`.

Say I have a few RegexParsers, and also a parser that does a lookup for a String:

```
trait NumbersParsers extends RegexParsers {
  def number = """\d+""".r
}

trait LookupParsers extends Parsers {
  type Elem = String
  def word = elem("word", (potential:String) => dictionary.exists(_.equals(x))
}
```

If I combine these parsers naively

```
object MyParser extends NumbersParsers with RegexParsers {
  def quantitive = number ~ word
}
```

I obviously get type errors because of the different types of `Elem`. How do I combine these parsers?

Comment: `xs.find(f).isDefined == xs.exists(f)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel somewhat responsible for answering this one since I asked and answered [Scala: How to combine parser combinators from different objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650254/scala-how-to-combine-parser-combinators-from-different-objects).

The quick answer would be, you can't combine different types of `Elem`. A different and elegant way to solve this problem uses `^?` to augment a regex parser with extra filtering.

It might be helpful to read up on [Combinator Parsing](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/combinator-parsing.html) in Programming in Scala:

> #### Parser Input
>
> Sometimes, a parser reads a stream of tokens instead of a raw sequence of characters. A separate lexical analyzer is then used to convert a stream of raw characters into a stream of tokens. The type of parser inputs is defined as follows:
>
> ```
> type Input = Reader[Elem]
> ```
>
> The class Reader comes from the package `scala.util.parsing.input`. It is similar to a Stream, but also keeps track of the positions of all the elements it reads. The type `Elem` represents individual input elements. It is an abstract type member of the `Parsers` trait:
>
> ```
> type Elem
> ```
>
> This means that subclasses and subtraits of Parsers need to instantiate class `Elem` to the type of input elements that are being parsed. For instance, `RegexParsers` and `JavaTokenParsers` fix `Elem` to be equal to `Char`.

So `Elem` is used by the lexical analyzer, which is responsible for chopping up your input stream into the smallest possible tokens that the parser wants to deal with. Since you want to deal with regular expression, your `Elem` is `Char`.

But don't worry. Just because your *lexer* gives you `Char`s that doesn't mean your *parser* is stuck with them too. What `RegexParsers` gives you is an implicit converter from a regex to `Parser[String]`. You can further convert them using `^^` operator (fully maps input) and `^?` operator (partially maps input).

Let's incorporate them into your parsers:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

scala> val dictionary = Map("Foo" -> "x")
dictionary: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(Foo -> x)

scala> trait NumbersParsers extends RegexParsers {
     |   def number: Parser[Int] = """\d+""".r ^^ { _.toInt }
     | }
defined trait NumbersParsers

scala> trait LookupParsers extends RegexParsers {
     |   def token: Parser[String] = """\w+""".r
     |   def word =
     |     token ^? ({
     |       case x if dictionary.contains(x) => x
     |     }, {
     |       case s => s + " is not found in the dictionary!"
     |     })
     | }
defined trait LookupParsers

scala> object MyParser extends NumbersParsers with LookupParsers {
     |   def quantitive = number ~ word
     |   
     |   def main(args: Array[String]) {
     |     println(parseAll(quantitive, args(0) ))
     |   }
     | }
defined module MyParser

scala> MyParser.main(Array("1 Foo"))
[1.6] parsed: (1~Foo)

scala> MyParser.main(Array("Foo"))
[1.1] failure: string matching regex `\d+' expected but `F' found

Foo
^

scala> MyParser.main(Array("2 Bar"))
[1.6] failure: Bar is not found in the dictionary!

2 Bar
     ^
```

Comment: Heh, I came here to answer my own question and you came up with the same thing. ^? must be the trick then.